# Ignoring/dropping NA factor level in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to prepare a ggplot pie chart on the number of cases of each factor. The thing is the factor only shows the type of defect, so most cases only have NA, which ruins the whole look of the chart. How do I get rid of it?

[image: Chart]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include in your question the code you used to generate that plot. (Even better would be reproducible code & data.)

Comment: Wow, thank you divibisan. I have red that post, but somehow missed it? Applied wronly? Still not sure, tried a bunch of different solutions, i might have missed that one. Thank you.